# scons: non-dependency actions ("phantom targets" ?)

Tags: scons

I'm not quite sure how to do this...

I want to declare some kind of action in an SConscript file:

```
Import('env');
arguments = ['foo','bar','baz'];
phantomTarget = env.DoSomething(arguments);
Return('phantomTarget');
```

and in the SConstruct file:

```
env['BUILDERS']['DoSomething'] = Builder(action='c:/foodir/foo.exe $ARGUMENTS');

   ...

phantomTarget = SConscript(['doc/SConscript']);
env.Alias('foo', phantomTarget);
```

so that at the command line I can type

```
scons foo
```

and it will run

```
c:/foodir/foo.exe foo bar baz
```

I can't seem to do this... scons wants to do dependency checking and I don't want to do that in this case :/

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just says there's nothing to be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what error you're seeing, maybe [PhonyTargets](http://www.scons.org/wiki/PhonyTargets) will help?